# JDA Check if channel exists

Tags: java, discord, discord-jda

Hello is there any option to check if the channel already exists? I have already tried sooooo many things but I can't code this I get errors or the code doesn't work and I didn't get any error in the console.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check by name:

```
JDA jda = jdaBuilder.build();
jda.awaitReady();

//Put the ID of your guild here
long guildID = 1L;

//check if the name of this channel exists
String channelName = "do I exist?";

//Ignoring case, whether the channel is found to already exist
boolean channelFound = false;

List<GuildChannel> channels = jda.getGuildById(guildID).getChannels();
for(GuildChannel channel : channels) {
    if(channel.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(channelName)) {
        channelFound = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```java
var guild = jda.getGuildById(serverId);
var channels = guild.getChannels();
```

You may get the channel list by this way.

Answer (score 0):

```
fun checkChannel(guild: Guild?, channelId: String): Boolean {
        try {
            var founded = false

            for (channel in guild?.textChannels!!) {
                if (channel.id == channelId) {
                    founded = true
                    break
                }
            }

            return founded
        }
        finally {
            //if use database closeConnection()
        }
    }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).